# Deduping across two columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to figure out how many unique products are available in a store. The problem is that the data is very messy. Fortunately, my counts can be rough estimates. At some point in the past, product names were replaced with product codes. Some products have a name, some products have a code, and some products have both. I need to dedupe across both columns. Some of the product names and product codes are not consistent.

For example, consider the following example...

```
data.frame(product_name = c("A", "B", "B", NA), product_code = c(NA, 1, 2, 1))
# product_name product_code
#            A           NA
#            B            1
#            B            2
#         <NA>            1
```

It should count two unique products. The first row is unique. The second and third share a product name while the second and fourth rows share a code.

Here's an example with more data. The large number of NA values is similar to my real dataset.

```
df <- data.frame(product_name = c(rep(LETTERS, 2), rep(NA, 48)),
           product_code = c(rep(NA, 10), sample(1:80, 90, replace = TRUE)))
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: _"first and fourth rows share a code"_. You mean "Second and fourth"?

Comment: Good catch, @useR!

Comment: Which `product_name`/`product_code` should be selected if the same `product_name` has two different `product_codes` like in your first example? Or are you just counting?

Comment: Do `product_code`s actually only contain digits (or `product_name`s only contain letters)?

Comment: Yes they do, @syknapptic. Every product_code contains only numbers and ever product_name contains only letters.

Comment: `df %>% filter(!(duplicated(product_name) | duplicated(product_code)))`

Comment: @Ryan the problem is that that's catching all the `NA` values as duplicates, which they are not necessarily

Comment: What is the expected count output of the data frame you've provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr` you can use [`distinct()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/distinct.html):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  distinct(product_name, .keep_all=TRUE) %>%
  distinct(product_code, .keep_all=TRUE)
```

Output:

```
  product_name product_code
1            A           NA
2            B            1
```

Add `count()` to get a count:

```
df %>% 
  distinct(product_name, .keep_all=TRUE) %>%
  distinct(product_code, .keep_all=TRUE) %>%
  count() # 2
```

Comment: The only problem here is the large number of NA values get reduced to one NA value.

Comment: Ok, in that case please update the example code you've provided to be representative of your actual data (multiple NAs and any other edge cases you are aware of)

Comment: Thanks @andrew_reece. I just added a note about the large number of `NA` values in the `df` example.

Comment: @Ryan Your solution works! Thank you! I'll give you the option of posting it as an answer for me to accept or having me accept andrew_reece's answer instead.